# Linking C programme with libclBLAS

Tags: c, gcc, opencl, amd-app

I'm trying to get started with clBLAS.
I'm using clBLAS-2.6.0 Release for ACL 1.0 Beta 1 on Linux 64bit.
Downloaded binaries from examples directory work fine on my hardware but my effort is to compile the simplest of them from source and link it to shared library.

Tree directory looks like this:

```
.
├── clBlasVersion.c
├── include
│   ├── clAmdBlas.h
│   ├── clAmdBlas.version.h
│   ├── clBLAS-complex.h
│   ├── clBLAS.h
│   └── clBLAS.version.h
└── lib
    └── libclBLAS.so
```

I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4 and following command:

```
 gcc -Iinclude -Llib clBlasVersion.c
```

fails with linking error:

```
/tmp/ccC9kQ9C.o: In function `main':
clBlasVersion.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `clblasGetVersion'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`AMDAPPSDKROOT` is set in environment and binary of this file, which is included in release, works showing correct version of `clblas`.
Any suggestion what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the linker to look into the `lib` folder for libraries that it may need (`-L`) option, but you are not specifying which library to link against.

Try using the `-l` option as in

```
gcc -Iinclude -Llib -lclBLAS clBlasVersion.c
```

Comment: Good point. Thanks! But in this case specifying library doesn't work. I solved problem with  `gcc -Iinclude clBlasVersion.c -Llib -lclBLAS -lpthread`. This latter solves  dependencies on threads library.

Comment: It's not correct to say that it doesn't work :). It was just not enough, I couldn't know based only on your question what other dependencies your code had (`pthread` in this case) :).

Comment: Thanks, but it actually didn't work unless I put name of source file between `-I` and `-L` options